# If value in column A of Sheet1 appears twice in column B of Sheet2, highlight value in Sheet1

Tags: filter, google-sheets, countif, google-sheets-formula, gs-conditional-formatting

Conditional Formatting - If a value in column A of sheet 1 appears twice in column b of sheet 2, highlight the cell in sheet 1

I've been messing with the indirect modifier to see if I can get this to work.

```
=COUNT(INDIRECT("'Order Confirmation'!B:B"),A1)
```

But this has currently just highlighted all the cells on sheet 1 column a. I have tried

```
=COUNT(INDIRECT("'Order Confirmation'!B:B"),A1>2)
```

---

```
=COUNT(INDIRECT("'Order Confirmation'!B:B"),A1=2)
```

and this has changed nothing. I would appreciate some assistance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if **Sheet2** is like:

[image: 0]

then **Sheet1** will be like:

```
=FILTER(A1, COUNTIF(FILTER(INDIRECT("Sheet2!B:B"), 
 COUNTIF(INDIRECT("Sheet2!B:B"), INDIRECT("Sheet2!B:B"))>1), A1))
```

[image: 0]

---

**UPDATE:**

```
=FILTER(A1, COUNTIF(FILTER(INDIRECT("'Order Confirmation'!B:B"), 
 COUNTIF(INDIRECT("'Order Confirmation'!B:B"), 
 INDIRECT("'Order Confirmation'!B:B"))>1), A1))
```

...as a custom formula because you have numbers in dataset not text

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. I've edited your suggested code to reflect my sheet names but I am unable to get the correct result.

Here are the screenshots

Rule : https://ibb.co/mTQjTF1
Rule Close Up: https://ibb.co/RTsn8Jw
Sheet 2: https://ibb.co/k0P6V5Z
Sheet 1: https://ibb.co/JjWbJ9C

I may be doing something wrong. Thank you!

Comment: @Scott here I made you demo sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17Uj0h1JcBNpt-Jja4zPa-ZQn4o-K23kxYG8p1gOSxKE/copy

Comment: Thank you @player0 I have tried your updated rule but was unable to get that to work too. I just requested access to the demo

Comment: It is view only. Thank you!